# Refresh the backstack Activities after Night Mode has changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, android-night-mode

I have seen a lot of questions and answers about recreating the current activity after changing the application's Night Mode, but I have seen nothing on how to refresh the back stack Activities.

Say I have the backstack **A > B > C**. Activity C allows to change the night mode by calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()`. After this call, the current Activity (C), can refresh its theme with `delegate.applyDayNight()` or `recreate()`.

However, when the user navigates back to B or A, the activities are still using the "old" mode, either day or night.

I tried to add something like that to the Activities:

```
override fun onResume() {
  super.onResume()
  delegate.applyDayNight()
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

I did multiple attempts to fix this:

One idea would be to recreate the backstack completely like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28799124/183665) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31197843/183665), but since the backstack is not static, it's not doable for me.

Another idea would be to have a class that handles the night mode change and provides a LiveData. Each Activity would listen to the LiveData for a mode change and call `recreate()`. However, we are stuck in an infinite loop because the Activity would recreate directly after starting to listen to the LiveData.

I find it hard to believe that I am the first one trying to refresh the Activities from the backstack after changing the night mode. What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try subclassing AppCompatDelegate

Comment: whenever you change the settings of the app you should recreate all the activities because just like language when changing the language in C activity A and B are still in the previous language. So its better to restart your App.

Comment: No, I want to keep my backstack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can detect when the day/night mode has changed, you can simply recreate an activity that is resumed when the back stack is popped.

In the following demo, there are three activities: A, B and C. A creates B and B creates C. Activity C can change the day/night mode. When C is popped, activity B sees the change in the day/night mode and calls `reCreate()` to recreate the activity. The same happens in activity A when activity B is popped.

The video below shows the effect. The light-colored background is the "day" mode and the dark is "night" mode.

I have created a [GitHub project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/DayNightBackStack) for this demo app. If this works as a solution, I can incorporate more text into the answer from the project.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's also what I resorted to do. It does not seem anyone have a better solution. Thanks !

Comment: @Jonas I am curious about what you find unsatisfactory about this solution.

Comment: This is the kind of code that ends up in a "BaseActivity". And I do everything I can to prevent having those monster classes that do a lot. Life of an Android developer I guess... :)

Comment: @Jonas I see what you mean. To be honest, I almost put this into a "BaseActivity" but kept it simple for the answer.

Comment: Hi If i have fragments inside activity B .It will all get recreated again

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing your back stack completely is probably overkill and may add some overhead/lag to the UX; and as you mentioned, most applications will not have access to a full, static back stack.

You are essentially describing a more general issue: global changes to the theme or WindowManager itself affect the subsequent drawing of views. But previous layouts for Activities in the stack may not be redrawn. It might seem odd for you in this situation, but there could also be many good reasons why one would not want to redraw an Activity in the stack if once the user goes back to it. And so this is not an automatic feature.

I can think of a couple of options:

1) Write a custom class inheriting from Activity that invalidates all it's views when it moves to the front of the stack again. E.g. in `onResume()` or `onRestart()`, call (if in `Fragment`)

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewid);
view.invalidate();
```

Use this custom Activity for all your activities that you want to keep consistent with the current day/night mode.

2) Use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. This helps keep all your logic in one place, and avoids the need for custom inheritance as above. You could invalidate your views here as needed as activities are paused/resumed. You could include a Listener, if it is your app that is changing the theme, and record as `SharedPreference`, for example.

To use, add the callbacks to your Application class:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void
    onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //can check type of Activity for custom behaviour, if using inheritance
        if(activity instanceof MainActivity) {
           mMainActivities.put(activity, new MainActivityEntry((MainActivity)activity));
            //...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void
    onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    } 

    @Override
    public void
    onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void
    onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if(activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        //...
        }
        //can update Entry properties too
        final MainActivityEntry activityEntry = mMainActivities.get(activity);

        if(activityEntry != null) {
        //record state /perform action
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void
    onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {


    }

    @Override
    public void
    onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {


    }

    @Override
    public void
    onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        recreate();
    }
```

You add the above codes to your MainActivity and it will work.

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

create a static boolean variable in the project and in each activity check if the boolean is true or false, then apply daylight and night based on value.

Comment: Thanks @raj. I would like to prevent having static variables.